# Maximum distance limit for D3 Force Layout?

Tags: d3.js, collision-detection, force-layout

I'm using a force layout with a small negative charge to avoid having SVG elements on top of each other. However, I need the items to remain within ~20px of their original location. Is there any means of limiting to the total net X/Y distance the items move?

Each SVG element represents a bus stop, so it's important that items do not overlap but also do not move too far from their original location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option for this in the force layout itself, but you can do that quite easily yourself in the function that handles the `tick` event:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  nodes.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + Math.min(0, d.x) + "," + Math.min(0, d.y) + ")";
  });
});
```

This would bound the positions to be to the top right of (0,0). You can obviously modify that to bound in any other way as well (potentially with a nested `Math.min`/`Math.max`). You could even do that dynamically by storing allowed position ranges with the element and referencing that.

See [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/index-alt.html) for an example that uses this technique to restrict the position of labels floated using the force layout.

Comment: Interesting - I should have been more specific in my question. In my implementation, rather than moving shapes contained within an SVG, I move the (small) SVG container itself using CSS top and left offsets. While I could potentially set the top change to Math.min(item.top, item.top+5), wouldn't identically placed items both shift to the identical bounds?

Comment: Not sure what you mean -- what you certainly could do with this approach is to record the original position and restrict any force directed movement to be within a 20x20 box of this.